# check if child exists in one to many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

User model: has_many :courses

Course model: belongs_to :user

```
def require_course
      unless #check if current user has course 
        redirect_to root_url
        return false
      end
end
```

i need a method that checks if current user has courses. What should i write to check if current_user has course.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for

```
def require_course
   redirect_to root_path if @user.courses.blank?
end
```

[Documentation about Object#blank?](http://www.railsapi.com/doc/rails-v3.0.1/classes/Object.html#M003406)

Answer (score 0):

How about `current_user.courses.size > 0` ?

Answer (score 0):

Even a shorter one:

```
redirect_to(root_url) if @user.courses.size.zero?
```

Answer (score 0):

Or even shorter:

```
def require_course
    redirect_to root_url if @user.courses.empty?
end
```

(note the `root_url` instead of `root_path`, as discussed [here](http://www.viget.com/extend/rails-named-routes-path-vs-url/).